# cv2.VideoCapture() taking extremely long time to connect and returning empty frames

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, udp

When executing the code

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://127.0.0.1:1080',cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
```

The script will yield for at least a minute, and then connect. Along with that, it seems that, almost at random, the script will completely break and cv2.VideoCapture() will return nothing. the stream is initiated with the command

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -f dshow -thread_queue_size 4096 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i video="OBS Virtual Camera" -f rawvideo -c:v mjpeg -qscale:v 0 -r 20 udp://127.0.0.1:1080
```

if that helps any.

I tried many different methods of starting the stream, color formats, and more. Still, they all had this issue.

(note this does work sometimes, but seemingly at random will completely stop working for many days to come, and then suddenly begin working)

Comment: test with ffmpeg to receive stream. if that behaves the same, untag opencv. review [mre]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I forgot to mention, UDP packets are being sent and can be seen with Wireshark immediately, but the code still yields for seemingly no reason.

Comment: (receiving with FFMPEG worked just fine, as well)

Comment: "the code yields", I see no code here. [tour], [ask], [mre], tyvm. -- I'm just here because you tagged OpenCV. if this is an ffmpeg issue (opencv uses ffmpeg), or your network is flaky, that would not be an OpenCV issue. MRE means figuring this out.

Comment: lt runs fine for a friend I had run it, so that seems like too specific of an issue for here, thank you for your help.